# Парсер ссылок

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Почему возвращает `Array`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Url`",$db) or die(mysql_error());
while($show = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$get =  @file_get_contents($show['url']);
preg_match_all('/href="(.*?)"/',$get,$matches2);
preg_match_all("/href='(.*?)'/",$get,$matches);
echo $matches2;
echo $matches;
}
```

Что в этом коде не так? Или можно как то по другому сделать

Comment: @NetSperes, т.к. ваш проект, судя по вопросам, состоит из одних регулярок, то сам Бог велел хоть немного попытаться вникнуть в суть этого вопроса. И повторю, что уже говорил - используйте человеческие парсеры и не извращайтесь.

Comment: Ну я найти так и не смог. И плюс все парсера сохраняют во отдельное место url. А мне нужен сборщик. Типо поискового паука только без сбора информации о странице, только ссылки.

Comment: Через что можно, но прогнать ссылки на  окочание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$matches = array_merge($matches[1], $matches2[1]);
foreach ( $matches as $key ) {
    echo 'url: ', $key;
}
```